# Count number of products since last 30 days in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have products I've sold which I would like to count for the last 30 days.

I've tried this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C;"=My_Item";A:A;">=11 novembre 2014")
```

It works. But now, instead of `"11 novembre 2014"`,  I would like something like `"TODAY()-30"` but it keeps returning me `"0".`

I assume it is a problem of date format but can't figure out what happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the column with dates, is formatted as date. Then I think this should work:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C;"=My_Item";A:A;">="&TODAY()-30)
```

or alternatively:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C="My_Item"; A:A>=today()-30)
```